# I recently got banned and want to fix deleted/current posts to get unbanned

Tags: support, reputation, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Just a little over a day ago, I got banned from Stack Overflow. I understand many of the reasons why.

The first is that, in the past, I would ask questions without doing research on their topics and post questions that were vague to others.

The second reason is that I deleted two questions that had low scores for not clearly describing the problem at hand.

There were also a few questions I know of that went unanswered. One of the posts I edited was closed a while ago, but has been rewritten to be much better now:
[Applying different CSS class on click using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182360/applying-different-css-class-on-click-using-jquery)

I'm now trying to answer to others' posts and editing questions. Is there any more that I can do? A couple of the questions that went unanswered were from the past, and I want to know, if I answer those questions, how would that affect my profile?

Definitely, for the future, I know to not go and ask questions without doing research, and to read over my drafts carefully to make sure I give good descriptions of my problems to other users, and to try as much as possible to help others.

I think this may be a duplicate of [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Comment: Looking at some of the edits you've made (http://stackoverflow.com/q/9182360/1015495 in particular) that you're definitely on the right track - that's a fantastic edit. Keep it up! edit: Also, you've got some solid, in-depth answers. Personally I think you'll be just fine.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Thank you very much and hope I'm on the right track. I'm definitely trying to make better for everyone what I post on here, especially when I get really stuck on something.

Comment: Please don't add your own "possible duplicate" notices at the top of posts... it's somewhat visually jarring/confusing for frequent users who are used to seeing the system-generated message there.

Comment: @PopularDemand Thank you for editing it. The moderators of the site do that, and should let them put that in there.

Comment: Actually, it's not even the moderators. When a question is closed with the "exact duplicate" reason, whether by moderators or community members, the _system_ (AKA [the Community user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)) automatically edits the duplicate question into a box at the top of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear,

- You can still edit questions and answers to make them better
- You can still answer questions and garner up votes

The system is just guiding you to a place where you can answer more than you ask until you get the hang of what the community votes as good contributions.

If there is another community here where you have good experience in providing answers, I would say go there and work on learning how to answer usefully questions and how the site review and editing tools work as you reach 1k and 2k reputation. At that point, you will be able to come back to Stack Overflow and see about undeleting / editing / improving your content here and perhaps by then, you will have provided enough good answers and edits to tip the system into allowing more questions for your account.

It's not impossible to get back in balance but it usually takes a few months of time and work to restore balance once you have gotten off track with too many questions deleted in ration to your upvoted content.

Comment: That I will definitely do. Thank you very much.